# How Does magento sales rule validate date and apply rule only if it is within range date

Tags: magento2, sales-rule

I was looking in to core module for sales rule but was unable to find the logic where it actually apply the filtration of current date and date added in rule that is `From` and `To`.

If i have created 3 rule and all are applicable on fronted also set different `from` and `to` date for each rule which date will be in priority.

I am curious to someone can please guide me where this logic is applied.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your question, you're asking about Price Rules in Marketing. If this is the case when at the same rules Magento will rely on the prosity field to apply the rules you created. You can see the attached picture: https://prnt.sc/11r113w

Comment: No i have created one custom module in which i have added these two field `startdate` and `enddate` so i would like to validate these date based on current date when getting collection

Comment: Yes. You can completely create a custom module to be able to perform the necessary functions according to your needs

Comment: But how??? that's the question